# ORACLE-way to use multiple parameter in wildcard (LIKE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find out the name from database which names are start with A to M or is there any way to use multiple parameter in wildcard (LIKE) for eg-

```
SELECT name
FROM database 
WHERE name LIKE (I want to search A to M here);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select ...
where  ... substr(name,1,1) between 'A' and 'M'
```

Possibly you want to:

```
select ...
where  ... upper(substr(name,1,1)) between 'A' and 'M'
```

This does have the advantage of potentially being indexable, although the index would probably only be used for much smaller ranges.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM database WHERE name LIKE '[A-M]'
```

Comment: Erm, does this work on Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_LIKE`, refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) for more in detail.

Try like this,

```
SELECT name FROM database WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '^[A-M]');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use substr or regexp_like or like.

The following statement is much simpler (and has the advantage that it can use an ordinary index):

```
SELECT name FROM database WHERE name >= 'A' AND name < 'N';
```

This query works on the basis that 'AA' > 'A' and all strings starting with 'M' sort before 'N'.

As far as index usage is concerned, I'm presuming that since you want half of the alphabet as the first letter that you will also be querying for half of the total number of rows and hence Oracle will prefer a full-table scan.